# python turtle - how to make the get_poly function to leave the shape unfilled

Tags: python, python-2.7, turtle-graphics

Is it possible to make the get_poly function to leave the shape unfilled.
For example, in this code can the red shapes with the blue fill be not filled with any color (white fill is not what i am looking for):

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen, Shape

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle(visible=False)
turtle.speed("fastest")
turtle.penup()

shape = Shape("compound")

for octogon in range(8):
    turtle.begin_poly()
    for _ in range(8):
        turtle.left(45)
        turtle.fd(20)
    turtle.end_poly()
    shape.addcomponent(turtle.get_poly(), "blue", "red")

    turtle.right(45)
    turtle.fd(60)

screen.register_shape("octogons", shape)

octopus = Turtle(shape="octogons")
octopus.penup()
octopus.speed("slowest")

octopus.goto(300, 200)
octopus.goto(-200, 200)

screen.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
shape.addcomponent(turtle.get_poly(), "", "red")
```